# Elfinder in Laravel how do I show only one directory in Google bucket

Tags: php, laravel, elfinder

I am able to user GoogleCloudStorage (gcs) and everything is working fine. What I have having trouble with is "hiding" all folders expect the one I want a user to have access to. In that one folder The user should have full access. I am using "barryvdh/laravel-elfinder": "^0.5.2",

My config file is default except for

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Upload dir
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The dir where to store the images (relative from public)
|
*/
'dir' => 'none',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem disks (Flysytem)
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Define an array of Filesystem disks, which use Flysystem.
| You can set extra options, example:
|
| 'my-disk' => [
|        'URL' => url('to/disk'),
|        'alias' => 'Local storage',
|    ]
*/
'disks' => [
    'gcs' => [
        'alias' => 'Cloud File Storage'
    ]
],
```

I have a middleware with two function that are NOT doing what I thought they would

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
        $disk = Storage::disk('gcs');
        $thisOrgId = current_org()->ID;
        $thisOrgName = current_org()->OrganizationName;
        $dirName = $thisOrgId;
        if ($dirName != '' && !$disk->directoryExists($dirName)) {
            $disk->makeDirectory($dirName);
        }
        $dirs = $disk->directories();
        $this->app = app();
        // $roots = $this->app->config->get('elfinder.roots', []);
        if (empty($roots)) {
            $roots = [];
            foreach ($dirs as $key => $dir) {
                // if the dir should be shown
                if($dir == $thisOrgId){
                    array_push($roots , [
                    'driver' => 'gcs', // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
                    'path' => $dir, // path to files (REQUIRED)
                    'startPath' => $dir,
                    'URL' => config('app.google.bucket_prefix'), // URL to files (REQUIRED)
                    'accessControl' => $this->access(
                        'hidden',
                        config('app.google.bucket_prefix').'/'.$dir,'gcs',
                        'accessControlData',
                        true,
                        '/'.$dir), // https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options-2.1#accesscontrol
                    'alias' => $thisOrgName,
                    'uploadAllow' => array('image'),
                    'uploadMaxSize' => '5M',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        array(
                            'pattern' => '/\'/', // Dont write or delete to this but subfolders and files
                            'read' => true,
                            'write' => true,
                            'locked' => true
                            )
                        )
                    ]);
                } else {
                    // hide the dir
                    array_push($roots , [
                        'driver' => 'gcs', // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
                        'path' => $dir, // path to files (REQUIRED)
                        'URL' => config('app.google.bucket_prefix'), // URL to files (REQUIRED)
                        'attributes' => array(
                            array(
                                'pattern'=> $dir,
                                'hidden'=>true
                                )
                            )
                        ]);
                }
            }
        }
        $opts = $this->app->config->get('elfinder.options', array());
        
        $bind = '';
        $plugin = '';
        $opts = array_merge(['bind'=>$bind,'plugin'=>$plugin,'roots' => $roots], $opts);
        
        return $next($request);
    }
function access($attr, $path, $data, $volume, $isDir, $relpath) {
    $basename = basename($path);
    return $basename[0] === '.'                  // if file/folder begins with '.' (dot)
             && strlen($relpath) !== 1           // but with out volume root
        ? !($attr == 'read' || $attr == 'write') // set read+write to false, other (locked+hidden) set to true
        :  null;                                 // else elFinder decide it itself
}
```

If I dump it looks like the example I have seen, What am I doing wrong?
[image]